# Altium STEP Models Aligning Underneath Board

Tags: altium

I'm trying to import a STEP model for a uFL connector and it's oddly misaligned beneath the board (see "3D uFL PCB" image attached). I've tried rotating it every which way but I cannot fathom how it wouldn't just align itself on the footprint. Photos attached. How do I get it to move up vertically onto the same top layer plane as the PCB?

[image: 3D uFL connector beneath PCB]
[image: 3D uFL STEP model settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Tools->3D Body Placement->Align Face with Board and click on the face of the 3D model you want to sit on the board.

Answer (score 1):

You're at the mercy of the origin defined by whoever designed the 3D model. Use the "Standoff Height" to adjust the height between the board and 3D model.